# Fixed position menu slowly disappears iOS?

Tags: ios, css, safari

As I scroll on iOS Safari only for my fixed position menu, it slowly scrolls with the page (but much slower pace?) until it disappears. It works in all other browsers/devices even the iOS simulator just fine...Any suggestions? My code is as stated here:

```
.mobile-nav {
    background-color: #455660;
    height: 58px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Nothing fancy, just your ordinary fixed pos. navigation. Again works on Chrome for iOS, and safari iOS simulator, Safari for OS X, etc...just real iOS devices with safari seems to be the problem.

Comment: Nevermind fixed it - for some reason had to do with another element overflowing? weird that an element not even touching this menu ruined it.

Comment: please consider to add this as an answer eventhough you asked the question yourself. This will help others to find the answer for the problem.